# Proof Euclidean division for ordinals

Tags: ordinals

I have a question about a proof from the book 'A First Journey through Logic' by M. Hils and F. Loeser:

**Lemma 1.6.3:** *Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be ordinals, with $\alpha \neq 0$. Then there exists a unique pair of ordinals $(\rho,\mu)$ such that $\rho < \alpha$ and $\beta=\alpha \mu + \rho$.*

The proof for the existence goes as follows: When $\beta=0$ there is nothing to prove. Assume $\beta \neq 0$. The mapping $f_0:\beta \rightarrow \alpha \times \beta:x \mapsto (0,x)$ is strictly increasing, hence $\beta \leq \alpha \beta$ by Lemma 1.5.8. If $\beta = \alpha \beta$, one sets $\mu=\beta$ and $\rho=0$. Otherwise, we have $\beta \in \alpha \beta$. Let $f$ be the unique isomorphism of ordered sets between $\alpha \beta$ and $\alpha \times \beta$ (Theorem 1.5.9). One sets $(\rho,\mu)=f(\beta)$ and one checks that $\beta=\alpha \mu + \rho$.

I have no idea why $\beta=\alpha \mu + \rho$ if $(\rho,\mu)$ is defined as $f(\beta)$. Can someone help me?

The results mentioned in the proof are:
**Lemma 1.5.8:** *Let $f: \alpha \rightarrow \alpha'$ be a strictly increasing map between two ordinals. Then $f(\beta)\geq \beta$ for every $\beta \in \alpha$.*
**Theorem 1.5.9:** *Every well-ordered set $X$ is isomorphic, as an ordered set, to some ordinal. Furthermore, the ordinal and the isomorphism are both unique.*

Also, $\alpha \beta$ is defined as the unique ordinal isomorphic to the reverse lexicographic product $\alpha \times \beta$.

Comment: Hint: try it out for some specific finite $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Say $\alpha = 11$ and $\beta = 3$. When you've figured out how it works in the finite case, you should see that the infinite case is essentially the same.

Comment: I guess it's simply $f^{-1}(x,y)=\alpha y+x$ for any $(x,y)\in \alpha\times\beta$.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you for your answer. I'm still not sure how I can do this since I don't know what $f$ is.

Comment: @Berci Thanks for your reply. If I could show that $f^{-1}(x,y)=\alpha y + x$ is an isomorphism between $\alpha \times \beta$ and $\alpha \beta$, then my problem would be solved. However, showing that this function is surjective just brings us back to what we were trying to prove in the first place, no?

Comment: $\alpha = 11 = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, 10\}$ and $\beta = 3 = \{0. 1, 2\}$ and $\alpha\beta = 33 = \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, 32\}$. Draw a picture of the cartesian product $\alpha \times \beta$ (squared paper will help). Now label the elements of $\alpha \times \beta$ with the elements of $\alpha\beta$ in in reverse lexicographic order. That labelling is $f$.

Comment: It's enough to prove that it's injective and its image is an ordinal.

Comment: @Berci How can I show that its image is an ordinal? I've been trying to show that it's transitive, but I can't figure it out...

Comment: Well, neither I am entirely sure how to do that rigorously..

Comment: @Berci: it's enough to prove that **what** is injective and has an image that is an ordinal? Your comment seems misleading to me.